# Get UITestControl from UITechnologyElement

Tags: c#

I have a code which gives back the UITechnologyElement by Name.
My purpose is to be able to call the "Mouse.Click()" method on this element, but for this I have to convert it to UITestControl, or get it from it, i don't know.

I haven't found any explanation about UITechnologyElement, or any correspondence between them.

So my question is, how I could click on this Element or maybe convert it to UITestControl for the same purpose?

```
private static UITechnologyElement IterateOnControl(UITechnologyElement parent, string name)
{
    UITechnologyElement te = null;
    UITechnologyManager TM = Playback.GetCoreTechnologyManager("MSAA");
    IEnumerator windowEnumerator = TM.GetChildren(parent, null);
    windowEnumerator.Reset();

    while (windowEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        UITechnologyElement current = windowEnumerator.Current as UITechnologyElement;
        if (current.Name == name)
        {
            te = current;
            break;
        }
    }
    return te;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have tested it, I found the answer...

```
//When you have the UITechnologyElement, you can create a WinControl from it by using this methode
WinControl result = (WinControl)UITestControlFactory.FromNativeElement(control.NativeElement, "MSAA");
//Now you have the WinControl so you can convert it into a special Type, eg. WinButton
WinButton wb = (WinButton)result;
//And invoke the Mouse.Click methode
Mouse.Click(wb, MouseButtons.Left);
```

That's all what I was needed. :)